# Manual ordering of Mylyn tasks in Local repository

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop, task, mylyn

The ordering of tasks in the Local task repository seems to be defined by the `Sort ...` menu (as one would expect).

Is there a way of ordering the tasks manually (but directly)? The UI supports drag-and-drop, even showing a little bar where the task would be placed when dragging, but dropping does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to rearrange the Task List manually.  Tasktop has gotten that request before, see

> 398: Rearranging / Sorting tasks https://tasktop.com/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398

If you want to see this feature, you can vote for the bug.  Tasktop does pay attention to what users ask for.

-- 
Kaitlin Duck Sherwood
Software Engineer, Support and Community, Tasktop
http://tasktop.com

Comment: I'll keep this as unanswered if its OK with you as there is currently no way of sorting them manually.

Comment: I just accepted the answer. Hopefully the feature will be implemented  in the future.